# Solution for Responsive button that Adjust Percentage bar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

[image]
I'm a beginner PHP. I used w3 template and CSS to do this on my own, the problem is I want to do with the button so that when I click it will adjust the percentage bar up and down.
Any solution for this, a small hint will be  appreciated

Answer (score 1):

A simple example to get you started, added a new class `btn_pro` to +/- button. Then add on click event to each of + / -.

Inside the click event, get the attribute value (where you set the +5 or -5 in HTML)

The `+` before `+pb` will force the string/text to become number type.

`if (newpb >= 0 && newpb <= 100)` update the progress bar, prevent to go lower than 0% or larger than 100%

Update the style yourself for like 0% etc.

```js
$('.btn_pro').on('click', function() {
  var change = $(this).attr('value');
  var pb = $('#progressbar > span').text();
  var newpb = +pb + +change;
  if (newpb >= 0 && newpb <= 100) {
    //update newpb now
    $('#progressbar > span').text(newpb);
    $('#progressbar').css('width', newpb + '%');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>


<p class="w3-large"><b><i class="fa fa-asterisk fa-fw w3-margin-right w3-text-teal"></i>Skills</b></p>
<p>Python</p>
<a class="w3-button w3-medium w3-circle w3-medium btn_pro" style="z-index:0" value="5">+</a>
<a class="w3-button w3-medium w3-circle w3-medium w3-margin-right btn_pro" style="z-index:0" value="-5">-</a>
<div class="w3-light-grey w3-round-xlarge w3-small">
  <div id="progressbar" class="w3-container w3-center w3-round-xlarge w3-teal" style="width:30%"><span>30</span>%</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much . It's really help